# Creating a directory with a concatenated name Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to create a directory its name is a concatenation between static string say "test_" and today's date. For instance: test_2015-04-28

I have tried this command but it does not work

```
mkdir test_'date +%F'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really a good post here but this is something you can do: `mkdir test_$(date +%F)`.

Comment: Thanks squiguy it works, but why is this not a good post?  I think it is acceptable to ask about linux commands regardless of the level of difficulty...there are tags for Linux and Ubuntu which I have used to target Linux experts..

Comment: I guess I will elaborate. I meant it isn't suited for this site. It would be just fine on another StackExchange site such as Unix and Linux or Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir test_$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

This will create a directory like test_20150428 . You can also make it like this:

```
mkdir test_$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

which will create a directory like test_2015-04-28.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: no problem . but i suggest if you have any question regarding Ubuntu  Ask it on Ask Ubuntu ! :)